# Почему StackTraceElement[0] всегда равен getStackTrace?

Tags: java

Почему `StackTraceElement[0]` всегда равен `getStackTrace`, а уже следующий (`[1]`) метод в списке - это уже сам метод, в котором вызвали `StackTraceElement[]`?

```
length of stack  7
0 - getStackTrace
1 - method5test
2 - method4test
3 - method3test
4 - method2test
5 - method1test
6 - main
```

Comment: потому что в момент генерации трейса на верхушке стека вызовов метод getStackTrace()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как для того, чтобы получить stack trace, выполняется вызов метода `getStackTrace()`, согласно общему правилу работы с методами, его контекст кладется в стек. Сам метод внутри себя работает итеративно, не добавляя контекстов вызова метода в стек, и по своему определению он ищет все контексты методов в стеке, поэтому всегда первым он найдет сам себя. Следующим по очереди находится контекст метода, который непосредственно запросил получить трассировку стека, так как вызов `getStackTrace()` пошел именно из него.

В принципе, всё вышеизложенное следует из [определения стека как области памяти, хранящей контекст программы для работы с функциями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA). Здесь в качестве элементов внутри стека выступает набор внутренних переменных вызванной функции и адрес возврата в вызывающую функцию. Ещё можно почитать [тут](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2lJoH18OJCIJ:http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/02/06/tutorial-java-8-understand-stack-and-heap/%2Bjava+stack+explanation&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&hl=ru&&ct=clnk) (сохраненная копия из гугла, англ.).

Comment: благодарю за развёрнутый ответ!